# What is the functionality of .js files inside node modules folder

Tags: angular, typescript

The npm packages are running as usual even if we delete the .js files from the respective node_modules folder. But is there a motive for the .js files yet?
Thanks in advance

Edited To Add:
the javascript files I edit in node_modules are not reflected in webpack in chrome console.
Is there anyway to make them get reflected?
Thanks in advance

Edited to Add:
As of Daniel W., edited js files are of no use and they get transpiled from .ts files
Another question: Is it possible to edit .ts file interfaces? (clarifying the question): Is every interface defined in the node_module itself? or is some of them protected?

Edited To Add:
I am using Angular-CLI. I edited the github project and used

```
npm run build
npm pack
```

and did

```
npm install E:/tmp/package.tgz
```

The

```
ng serve
```

is refreshing the files. But when I run the dist folder, the old js files are not refreshing(been trying this for 3-4 days). I tried

```
npm cache clean --force
```

also. How to refresh angular cli output?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "running as usual"? Did you maybe compile all files into a single one, to avoid loading tons of files from `node_modules` on executing your application?

Comment: @NicoHaase I deleted the ag-grid-community-angular.js from node_modules dist folder and it did not affect the ng build. Is interface (from .ts file) loading from somewhere else? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should give more background: How do you run the app? If you use runtime <strike>compiling</strike> transpiling, the .ts files could get automatically converted to .js files in-memory.

Comment: @DanielW. Does that mean edited js files don't get reflected in webpack? I am using `ng serve`

Comment: @DanielW. Is it possible to edit Interfaces of .ts files?

Comment: It depends on how you treat the files (run the app). Down to the ground, `node` cannot run .ts files, but there are different ways to hand the .js over to node.

Comment: [`ng serve`](https://angular.io/cli/serve) - "Builds and serves your app, rebuilding on file changes." The way that happens depends on the `--configuration`.

Comment: @DanielW. Hi Is it possible to locate and edit the empty interface methods of d.ts files? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reflect changes in `npm install E:/tmp/package.tgz`
by changing the `ng build`
flags. Example, once we run `ng build --prod`
the changes will reflect again only if we run another flag like `ng build --prod --aot=false`.
But I have dropped the project and went back to AngularJS since my team leader says he couldn't understand the Angular 13 language. Thanks for spending your valuable time mates